# Installing Wine on Raspberry Pi running PiNet

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

I am setting up a small network of Pi 3 thin-clients running PiNet.  It is my understanding that PiNet works in much the same way that LTSP does, in that the boot image on the SD card causes the Pi to connect to the Ubuntu server and behave in much the same way a PXE-boot LTSP client would (no files or processes are stored/executed on the Pi, the Pi acts simply as a KVM).

If this is correct, it would lead me to believe that my preliminary searches, that indicated I could not install Wine in this environment, were wrong.  So, I reach out here and see if anyone knows how to accomplish this.  I need to have Wine available to all users of the system, once that is established, I can handle moving the software around.

If this works like LTSP, I would imagine all I have to do is install Wine on the server it's self, however, the PiNet installer indicates that it needs to install some things, and that confuses me, as I would think anything I install is *technically* installed in the user environments as well.

What am I missing?